# Which hardware is failing?

Tags: overheating, cpu-cooler, bsod, machine-check-exception

What component should I replace?

My home build PC is acting up. I'd like to only have to replace what is obviously broken.  I was getting blue screens like this.

From three days ago.

> WHEA-Logger:
>
> A fatal hardware error has occurred.
>
> Reported by component: Processor Core
> Error Source: Machine Check Exception
> Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error
> Processor ID: 0

Then it wouldn't stay powered on for more than a few minutes. Like the MB just does a forced shutdown without telling the OS. I think it was so hot even the bios would lock up.

I tuned the bios to put the fans on duty instead of silent. Now I'm back to the first behavior

From today

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000124 .
> (0x0000000000000000, 0xfffffa800d93b028, 0x00000000b64a4000, 0x0000000000000175)

SpeedFan reports Temp1 60C when idle. And up to 85C when all cpu's are in use.

> Windows7 sp1
>
> AMD Phenom ii x6
>
> Asus crosshair V formula
>
> corsair h60 cooler
>
> 32GB ram.

I've tested each stick of ram by itself and I get the same behavior.

The most frustrating part is I left the machine on all day and it's fine. But about twenty minutes into active use. (even if I'm checking speedfan for overuse), It just fails.

Comment: We need to know which drivers were loaded.  Use BlueScreenViewe to determine this information and provide it to us.

Comment: Do you have enough fans? Are they blowing the right way to create a good airflow? What temps are the hard drives? Run a smart tool

Comment: @slhck That's not very nice to delete my answer. You guys are quite the sticklers. Should I copy paste it into 2-3 comments instead?

Comment: @DaveRook HDDs are 30 and 38C. gpu is 50C. core temp 57C.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama, I don't think your 'post' would need to go over 2 or 3 comments - when you remove the waffle, you'd fit it into 1 comment easily.

Comment: This may be useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560537(v=vs.85).aspx ... Also, is your PC overclocked? At the moment, I *think* you may need to buy a new CPU, but, what is the PSU?

Comment: Does event viewer show more detail?

Comment: Source: WHEA-Logger Event ID: 18, does that help?

Comment: I don't think it's overclocked but it is a RoG mainboard designed for overclocking enthusiasts.

Comment: They deleted my answer, so I'll try to summarize here. 60-85C is WAAAAY too hot for AMD processors. Anything above 55C would make me nervous, and some specific googling for Phenom II X6's reveals a max range of 62-71C. It sounds like you have some major cooling problems. http://www.overclock.net/t/1134229/amd-cpus-max-temps

Comment: What case do you have? What is the fan configuration? Are all fans working? Have you cleaned the dust out of the CPU heatsink lately using compressed air?

What STOP code are you getting from the Windows bluescreens? And you said you're getting a combination of bluescreens and spontaneous shutoffs?

"All CPU's?" Do you have more than 1 CPU installed? Is this a server?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama all good questions. Dust cleaned. Fans work. I mentioned I have the corsair h60 which is a self-contained water cooler. one cpu, desktop machine.

Comment: I have the Corsair H80 liquid cooler and I rarely go above 48C. Very odd that your CPU is getting so hot with such a good cooling system. It's definitely worth investigating why your CPU is getting so hot. Did you forget to apply thermal compound? I agree with user1793963 below... It's definitely worth checking the seating of your cooling system to your processor.

Comment: I suppose I should note that this system was assembled over two years ago and hasn't had any hardware changes in months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible the heatsink got loose and there is a small gap between it and the processor. To fix it you have to remove the heatsink, clean it and apply new thermal paste.

There is no way to be sure if this is the problem in your case, but it's easy and cheap to fix (compared to a new CPU).